# Python + Selenium Grid

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I managed to set up a Node + Hub on my own pc.

I have a file called `run_parallel_test.py` that simply just creates a process to execute test scripts based on sys args, which are just browser configs with capabilities.

The command would be as follows:

```
python run_parallel_tests.py testrunner.py browsers.json
```

`testrunner.py` is basically Python's unittest framework executing test suites.

The issue I am having is before, I was hooked with browser stack and not selenium grid, I was able to pass browser capabilities such as this:

```
    [
  {
    "browser": "Chrome",
    "browser_version": "71.0 beta",
    "os": "Windows",
    "os_version": "10",
    "resolution": "1920x1080"
  },
  {
    "browser": "Firefox",
    "browser_version": "blah blah",
    "os": "Windows",
    "os_version": "10",
    "resolution": "1920x1080"
  }
]
```

Now with a grid, those capabilities no longer work, and I have created barebone capabilities to simply run my tests such as:

```
    [
  {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "browser_version": "71.0 beta",
    "platform": "WINDOWS"
  },
  {
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "browser_version": "64.0 beta",
    "platform": "WINDOWS"
  },
  {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "platform": "WINDOWS"
  },
  {
    "browserName": "internet explorer",
    "platform": "WINDOWS"
  }
]
```

The issue is, I no longer can set the resolution etc via my JSON file config as I was before when using browser stack. Is there a way to set up the resolution?

I have checked: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
I could not find the documentation for it. Maybe I am looking at the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set that via the server/grid because they don't setup a container for your browser to run in like browser stack. You will need to set the browser size in your python code via [the set_window_size command](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=window#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_size)

Comment: Hmm if thats the case, whats the best way to differentiate and run resolution based on desktop/tablet/mobile. Capabilities would be the same, but If I hard code the resolution it will always be whatever the code implies. 

I see there is a property for desiredCapabilities: commandLineFlags maybe leverage this?